# Definition of a norm of a vector space using a subset of the vector space.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let X be a vector space and D be a subset of X satisfying

a) x, y $\in$ D implies $\lambda x+ \mu y\in D$ whenever $|\lambda|+|\mu|<1$

b) If $x\in X$ and $x \neq 0$, there are nonzero $\lambda$ and $\mu$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\lambda x \in D$ and $\mu x \notin D $.

Prove that $||x||:= \inf\{t>0 | x \in tD\}$ defines a norm on X.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I did some part of the proof as follows:

i) If $||x|| =0$, we show that $x=0$:

By definition of $\inf$, let $\epsilon >0$. There exist $t_1$ and $d\in D$ such that $x = t_1D$ and $t_1 \leq \inf \{t>0 | x \in tD\}+\epsilon$ or $t_1 \leq ||x||+\epsilon$. So if $||x||=0$, we get $t_1\leq\epsilon$. Then we can conclude that $t_1=0$. So $x=t_1d=0$.

However, I have a problem in the other direction: If $x=0$, then $||x||=0$.

ii) $\forall \lambda\in \mathbb{C}$, $||\lambda x||=|\lambda|||x||$:

for $\lambda>0$: $||\lambda x|| = \inf \{t>0 | \lambda x \in tD\} = \inf \{t>0 | x \in \frac{t}{\lambda}D\}$. By changing the variable $t'=\frac{t}{\lambda}$, we get $||\lambda x|| = \inf \{\lambda t'>0 | x \in t'D\} = \lambda \inf \{t'>0 | x \in t'D\} = \lambda ||x||$.

However, I have a problem proving with $\lambda <0$ or $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

iii) I have no idea to prove the triangle inequality $\forall x, y \in X $, we get $||x+y||\leq||x||+||y||$.

Comment: Hi Kourosh. It is okay to answer your own question when you give a mostly complete answer. But in this case, I think it makes more sense to put this text into your question, as your attempt.